# How to filter/sum array data by year/quarter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, filter, urlfetch

Trying to consolidate dividend data by year and quarter from an object from this [URL](https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/BAYRY?formatted=true&lang=en-US&region=US&interval=1d&period1=1451624400&period2=1577854799&events=div&useYfid=true&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com).
I was able to retrieve dividend date and dividend amount from the object and convert the dividend date to YYYY Q format with the following codes.  From the results, I like to remove any dividend arrays outside of year 2018 and 2019, and consolidate the remainder by year and quarter only between 2018 and 2019, like this picture.  I like to put 0 if no dividend data in a given quarter, and sum any multiple dividend amounts in a given quarter.  How can I achieve that?

[image]

```
function test() {
  const url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/BAYRY?formatted=true&lang=en-US&region=US&interval=1d&period1=1451624400&period2=1577854799&events=div&useYfid=true&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com';
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true }).getContentText();;
  const obj = JSON.parse(res);
  const dividend_id = Object.keys(obj.chart.result[0].events.dividends);
  var dividend = dividend_id.map((id => [
    obj.chart.result[0].events.dividends[id].date,
    obj.chart.result[0].events.dividends[id].amount]));

  var dividend = dividend.map(arr => [new Date(arr[0] * 1000).toLocaleDateString('en-US'), arr[1]]);
  console.log(dividend)

  var dividend = dividend.map(arr => [(arr[0].slice(-4) + ' Q' + (getQuarter(new Date(arr[0])))), arr[1]]);
  console.log(dividend)

  function getQuarter(date = new Date()) {
    return Math.floor(date.getMonth() / 3 + 1);
  }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code included in the question? If you didn't wrote the code you should provide proper attribution otherwise it's plagiarism even if you adapted from another post from this site. Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: Understood!  I will keep it in mind, going forward.  Seems like I can't edit this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it.  I would use the Date to get the year and build an array for each year `[year,0,0,0,0]`.  Then use the year to find the array for that year and the month to find the quarter as index into the arrays.

```
function getDividends() {
  const url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/BAYRY?formatted=true&lang=en-US&region=US&interval=1d&period1=1451624400&period2=1577854799&events=div&useYfid=true&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com';
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true }).getContentText();;
  const obj = JSON.parse(res);
  const dividend_id = Object.keys(obj.chart.result[0].events.dividends);
  var dividend = dividend_id.map((id => [
    obj.chart.result[0].events.dividends[id].date,
    obj.chart.result[0].events.dividends[id].amount]));

  let quarters = [];

  dividend.forEach( item => {
      let day = new Date(item[0]*1000);
      let year = day.getFullYear();
      if( year > 2017 ) {
        let i = quarters.findIndex( quarter => quarter[0] === year );
        if( i < 0 ) {
          quarters.push([year,0,0,0,0]);
          i = quarters.length-1;
        }
        let j = Math.floor(day.getMonth()/4)+1;
        quarters[i][j] = quarters[i][j]+item[1];
      }
    }
  );

  dividend = [];
  
  quarters = quarters.forEach( quarter => {
      for( let i=1; i<5; i++ ) {
        dividend.push([(quarter[0]+" Q"+i),quarter[i]]);
      }
    }
  )
  console.log(dividend);
}
```

Execution log

```
9:33:08 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:33:09 AM  Info    
  [ [ '2018 Q1', 0 ],
  [ '2018 Q2', 1.2289999999999999 ],
  [ '2018 Q3', 0 ],
  [ '2018 Q4', 0 ],
  [ '2019 Q1', 0.789 ],
  [ '2019 Q2', 0 ],
  [ '2019 Q3', 0 ],
  [ '2019 Q4', 0 ] ]
9:33:09 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Reference

- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Date object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)
- [Array.findIndex()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp)

Comment: It's working.   It's helping me a lot expand your concept to my real application that sometimes there is no even 2018 data.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @TheWizEd, one small change in your code.  ```let j = Math.floor(day.getMonth()/4)+1;``` needs to be changed to ```let j = Math.floor(day.getMonth()/3+1); ```. If you test these, you can see the issue,  ```console.log(Math.floor((new Date('2023-11-24')).getMonth() / 3 + 1));```
  ```console.log(Math.floor((new Date('2023-11-24')).getMonth() / 4) + 1);```

Comment: No I tested it and as you can see from the Execution log it works.  Months 0,1,2,3 / 4 = 0 +1, 4,5,6,7 / 4 = 1 +1, are the index into the array `[year,0,0,0,0]`